# get actionbar height in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to get actionbar height in my oncreate method, not after views created like this
**first way**

```
 content.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            Log.d(tag + " onCreate", "getSupportActionBar().getHeight()=" + getSupportActionBar().getHeight());
            return true;
        }
    });
```

for that, I use this code
**second way**

```
final TypedArray styledAttributes = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
    int mActionBarSize = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
    styledAttributes.recycle();
```

but my problem is when I use first way I get actionbar height 56, and when i use secound way i get actionbar height 48.
and i think first way is correct answer but i dont want to wait until views created.
can anyone help me about this?
"i use htc desire 200 for test with density mdpi"

Comment: Since you know that 48 dp seems to be the correct one, why not use the value itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two different height between these two methods because they are returning the value of two different things. The first method returns the actual `ActionBar` height. The second method returns the value of the android attribute `actionBarSize`.

The correct method to have the real `ActionBar` height is the first but if you say that you don't want to wait the creation of the views, if you are using `Toolbar` you can set via xml his height to `?android:attr/actionBarSize` and use the second method wherever you want to get the height in pixels.